# PHP Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory when creating directory

Tags: php, linux, filesystems, mkdir

I'm trying to recursively create directories, but I get this PHP warning:

Code:

```
<?php mkdir('data/1/0', 0755, true);
```

Output:

```
PHP Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in /home/myScript.php on line 1
```

This is running on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to write an FAQ style question, but this particular issue is too localized; the error already suggests that some part of the path is not a directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: But when I encountered the problem,I searched the stackoverflow.com,but nothing useful found.None of them came up with the problem I mentioned below.I do not think the issue is too localized.The error does not suggests PART of the path is not a directory,okay?

Comment: This question helped me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from the manual book, we can see:

```
bool mkdir( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

When we try to `mkdir` `data/1/0`, actually we can `mkdir` `0/` under the directory `data/1`. But when `data/1` happens to be a file instead a directory, `php` will issue a warning `PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory`

So, when you come with this warning, you can check that the prefix of the pathname is a file, where a directory was expected.